# ISS Docking / Undocking schedule availability

Tags: iss, docking

Is there a website or other API from where the ISS planned docking / undocking events could be available?

I would also be interested in historical docking undocking events.

Thank you very much in advance! Manny

Comment: Welcome to space.stackexchange.com! I'd like to mention that self-research is highly encouraged here. Google is out friend ) And Wikipedia - maybe not always - but usually is our friend too, at least as starting point ) Some answers on basic questions can be obtained by googling and fast look on results.

Comment: Thank you very much @Heopps, I understand what you you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncrewed_spaceflights_to_the_International_Space_Station

(see table)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_human_spaceflights_to_the_International_Space_Station

(see table)

The articles also contain planned flights, but of course the times can be changed (because of weather, technical or management issues).

UPD:

For future flights - spaceflightnow.com is useful. The authors usually keep eye on latest launch schedule changes (Wikipedia can be less operative). The scehdule is here:

https://spaceflightnow.com/launch-schedule/

Space agencies in current time usuallly stick to the philisophy "better safe than sorry". Safety is priority, better to postpone a launch some days, weeks or ever months than to have a disaster and lose much more.

Even non-fatal mishaps, like Boeing CTS-100 test flight or Soyuz MS-10 in-flight abort are huge management blows. They force to rework all the shedules and postpone some planned activities for months if not more.

From my experience, usually dates of Russian Souyz launches to ISS change more rare than NASA's launches.

Comment: Thank you very much @Heopps, this is probably the closest that we can get from what I understand. I was hopeful that exact future docking / undocking times would be available.

Comment: @M.Pap - I added some more info.